# Sitefinity cannot add RelatedMedia with content type

Tags: image, module, sitefinity, contenttype

I am currently having issues adding a `relatedmedia` field type to a content type inside a module. The issue isn't when I add the field, but when I try and edit/create the content and where it says:

> Content from this type cannot be selected because the module or the source providing its content is deleted or deactivated.

There is already a field called `profileimage` of type `Media` which seems to be working just fine. From what I've read Media is pre sitefinity 7.0 and `RelatedMedia` is for 7.0 and above.

I looked through some of the other sites that are on this setup, and some of the other content types have `RelatedMedia` field types set up and working. I have also looked at [this G+ page](https://plus.google.com/105960598610765683395/posts/TciEA62TcFy) but not sure if this is the culprit.

We are running sitefinity  7.2.5310.0.

Comment: Which module are you adding it to? It is a stretch but it could be a hidden field some where.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a custom module with about 6 different dynamic content types in it. None of the other content types have this type of field in it. Just "Media".

Comment: Can you supply any more info about what type of content you are trying to relate? Is it a dynamic module, documents, images?

Comment: I'm trying to let users add another image to it. Parent content type is none, and it contains "Title - short text","summary - long text", "leadership-classification", "position-short text", "profileimage - media".

Comment: I asked in the siteinity forum, and was pointed to [link](http://docs.sitefinity.com/migrate-related-data-with-the-migration-assistant). I'm not sure if what they're saying is that I have to upgrade the media item to a Related Media item because they can't coexist on the same item or they didn't understand my question.

Comment: Yes, there are around 40 sites under the main umbrella

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set up the related media you had a choice for the provider if you didn't select "default site source" I could see why it wouldn't be able to find media items.

Make sure to set "default site source" as your provider if you only want to access that sites media, or select the proper provider for the site you are if you are only using it on one multisite, make sure to only enable the module on that site as well

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try this and see if this was the issue.